# How should I get platform specific jni headers in linux for cross-build?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm new to the Jni environment and I want to cross compile the shared library builds using the docker so the Jar can be packed easily from any platform and can include the required shared libraries.

I had more attempts to do via CMake and Meson build system but never succeed in them, so I shifted to docker, luckily I found a repo ([dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross)) which provide prebuilt images for cross compiling C/C++ toolchains.

Since the toolchains are for the windows I would have no problems when compiling with that toolchain,  platform-dependent code (like `long` which is 32 bit in windows) should be compiled and linked through the cross-compiler and platform dependent libraries will build fine.

So, I only need the Jni headers to build. The problem is I couldn't install the Windows JDK in Linux environment, so I am not able to get the header files (`jdk/include/win32`).

How shall I proceed getting the header files for the build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [OpenJDK headers in the github repository](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.base).

Although that's not properly arranged as one in the JDK installation, its worth hardcoding those paths or use a simple bash/python script :)

Hopefully its helpful. Since its nowhere written or guided to be used. Many blog posts just download extract the whole jdk for all three OS, and then put them on their repo, which probably isn't be best idea because those headers are licensed as GPL2 and any OSS having non-GPL2 licenses (like MIT) may suffer to not do such things.

But alright, we found it so we can remotely use them as a dependency on any OSS projects!

Comment: You have to add `jni_md.h` and `jni.h`

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Yeah, I automated the per-platform files on a docker image: https://github.com/Animeshz/keyboard-mouse-kt/pull/4/files :) Now single gradle build command and in ~5-8s build is completed!